# Is there a signature algorithm that satisfies "Sign_x1(m)+Sign_x2(m)=Sign_(x1+x2)(m)"?

Tags: cryptography, signature

**Question:**

Is there a signature algorithm that satisfies

```
sigma_1 = Sign_x1(m) and Verify_X1(sigma_1) = true
sigma_2 = Sign_x2(m) and Verify_X2(sigma_2) = true

sigma = sigma_1 + sigma_2

Verify_X(sigma) = true.
```

**Description:**

- 'x1' and 'x2' is private key.
- 'Sign_x1(m)' means signing message 'm' with the private key 'x1'.
- The operation '+' is not just the addition in mathematics, and it represents a kind of computation.
- The corresponding public keys of 'x1' and 'x2' are 'X1' and 'X2'.
- The corresponding public key of 'x1+x2' is 'X', and we can use it to verify the signature produced by 'sigma_1 + sigma_2' by the **same signature verification algorithm** as verifying the individual signature.

Comment: if '+' is defined as multiplication mod n then RSA satisfies this property.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about cryptography https://crypto.stackexchange.com. You may want to look up *homomorphic encryption* first. Oh, and [this wikipedia article, if you're up to it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_signatures_for_network_coding)

Comment: Also see wikipedia's [Malleability (cryptography)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malleability_(cryptography)). And the paper [Malleable Signatures: New Definitions and Delegatable Anonymous Credential](https://smeiklej.com/files/csf14.pdf) might be useful.